# How to write a nested handler for rapidjson deserialization?

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I'd like to write a nested handler for consumption of json using rapidjson.

I've modeled my basic handler along the lines of [the official simplereader example](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/blob/master/example/simplereader/simplereader.cpp). This is fine for flat structures, but now I need to expand the parsing to nested objects as well.

The way I see it, I can either

1. have a central handler that keeps track of various domain objects to create and subsequent parse values into, or
2. I can change handler while parsing

Technically, I know how to do 1., but 2. seems like a neater solution, if possible.

Is it possible to change handlers mid-stream? Is there a best practice for doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delegate the events to other handlers. This is often done by:

1. Applying the [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) internally in your custom handler. So that the handler can delegate the events to the current state object via polymorphism (a.k.a. virtual functions).
2. Using `switch-case` to do the delegation with an `enum`.

The first one has advantage if you need to deal with recursive structure. You can push the pointers of state objects in a stack.

Comment: Thanks Milo! Option 1 sounds like a neat solution.